# Unable to connect to the application with IP address

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, visual-studio

I created a web application in Visual Studio 2017 using C# , MsSQL. It is working fine in the local host http://localhost:56169/, but it is not working when I am trying to access the application from other computer within the LAN with IP address. Please help me on this. 
Thanks.

Comment: What specifically are you attempting and how specifically is it failing?  This sounds more likely to be a networking issue or perhaps a server configuration issue than a code issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable IIS Express to be allowed for remote connect and open the firewall port.

Open your Advanced Firewall panel in Windows and allow port 56169 in.

Then open a command prompt in Administrator mode and run this:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://vaidesg:56169/ user=everyone
```

Open your applicationhost.config file from either:

```
%userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config
```

or

```
$(solutionDir)\.vs\config\applicationhost.config
```

Add the entry and this binding with your machine name in place of YOUR_MACHINE_NAME

```
 <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":56169:YOUR_MACHINE_NAME" />
```

[Here is a blog post about it](https://blogs.iis.net/vaidyg/serving-external-traffic-with-webmatrix-beta)

Another way you can also try is [iis-proxy](https://github.com/icflorescu/iisexpress-proxy)

Open command prompt and run

```
npm install -g iisexpress-proxy
```

and then

```
iisexpress-proxy 56169 to 81
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried netsh http add urlacl url=http://vaidesg:56169/ user=everyone

Comment: And the Error is HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

Comment: I edited the response and added a binding you need to add also.

Comment: You can also achieve the same with no config changes using our free VS extension called "Conveyor".  Find it in the Extensions dialog, and once installed it automatically opens a new port where you can send traffic and get around the IIS Express limitation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the debugger to look at the application from Visual Studio then it is running from IIS express or a dev web server and is not designed to be accessed from other machines.

If you want to access it from another machine you need to deploy your application to an IIS web site and configure it to have proper authentication and authorization for external access from users.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could you help me how to deploy and configure my application to an IIS website?